# Gradle Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: java, android, gradle, support-v4

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }

    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
    }

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile('com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+') {
        exclude module: 'gson'
    }
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.androidprogresslayout:library:2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
}
```

but every time I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
    java.util.zip.ZipException:
        duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter$CursorToStringConverter.class
```

Here is the `gradlew -q dependencies App:dependencies --configuration compile` result:

[image]

From the bottom that you can see, I've not added `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement` lib, yet it's shown with no reason?

**FOUND THE SOLUTION**

I check gradle's console while its dexing the dependencies and I saw;

```
Dexing \app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.JakeWharton\ViewPagerIndicator\2.4.1\jars\libs\android-support-v4.jar took 1499
```

Which is adding the oldest support-v4 lib as a jar. I've deleted the ViewPagerIndicator dependency from build.gradle and add it's classes manually.

Now the weirdest problem got solved.

Comment: Are you using some jars?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti actually i didn't use any jars. But somehow i created new empty project and copied the classes and res files to the new one. While gradle is dexing i saw Dexing \app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.JakeWharton\ViewPagerIndicator\2.4.1\jars\libs\android-support-v4.jar took 1499

which is adding the support-v4 jar the oldest one. I deleted viewpagerindicator lib from dependencies list and added it's classes manually. Now the strange problem is solved.

Comment: It is not strange. You were adding the same class with different versions twice

Comment: but i've used exclude tag from gradle which is not actually worked.

Comment: Check the answer below. It explain why the exclude tag doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding twice the support-library v4.

It happens because you are using

```
compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar'
```

You are getting this library from the jitpack.
[This library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) **adds the support library as a jar** and not as a gradle dependency.

It means that the pom file doesn't have a dependency and you can't exclude the jar file with gradle because the jar is inside the aar file (without a pom how can gradle know that these files should be excluded?).

You can check the files in the jitpack repo:

- [pom file](https://jitpack.io/com/github/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/2.4.1/ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1.pom)
- [aar file](https://jitpack.io/com/github/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/2.4.1/ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1.aar)

Comment: i didn't know that. Thank you so much for the explanation, next time i'll be careful while adding dependencies for this kind of issues.